# Create new email account programmatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imap, email

I can't seem to find an answer to this. How would I go about creating new email accounts programatically. I have users sign up for my service and would like to create an email account for them to use theirname@mysite.com but cant seem to figure it out.

I am using ruby on rails.

Comment: I guess you are about your own mail server. May be you should look for api of the tool with which you create this server? Do I understand correctly your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a great article on how to use action mailer at RubyOnRails.org [Action_Mailer_Basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) 
This walk through provides examples on how to create emails using scripts.  You can also store your mail user accounts in a database per the email server documentation.  A script can be used create user accounts in the database and then email the user credentials back to the user who signed up to your site.  This framework should help you resolve your problem.